# Achieving skip condition in chef inspec

Tags: chef-infra, inspec

Am trying to achieve condition that if the group exists in the server it should pass & if not exists it should skip and should not show as failure

```rb
describe.one do 
  describe 'testgroup'  do 
    expect(bash("ipa group-show testgroup").exit_status).to eq 0 
    it { should exist }
  end 

  describe 'testgroup' do 
    expect(bash("ipa group-show testgroup").exit_status).to_not eq 0 
    it { should_not exist }
  end
end
```

After executing using:

```
# inspec exec testgroup_test.rb
```

It throws error output as:

```
undefined method 'bash' for Rspec::ExampleGroups (No method Error).
```

Please advice, how to achieve such condition testing in inspec.

Comment: If its ok for the group to not exist, why test it at all? Not sure you would want to write a test that doesn't fail if the condition doesn't match.

Comment: the script is common for 2 different environments, in one environment if its available the test should pass and in other env the group is not available it should skip and wont show failure

Answer (score 0):

To address the error message first before solving the environment specific tests, the correct way of testing a command's result is to use the [command resource](https://docs.chef.io/inspec/resources/command/).

Let's consider a case when I want to pass the test when the command executes successfully, otherwise fail:

```rb
describe command('ipa group-show testgroup') do
  its('exit_status') { should eq 0 }
end
```

Now, let's say we have 2 environments - "dev" and "qa". We can use [inputs](https://docs.chef.io/inspec/inputs/) to conditionally execute the tests.

For an example: We can define an input called `env`. In "dev" environment it may not be necessary that this command will succeed. While in "qa" it should succeed.

```rb
# In "dev" any return code from command is ok
if input('env') == 'dev'
  control "ipa-group-dev" do
    describe command('ipa group-show testgroup') do
      its('exit_status') { should be >= 0 }
    end
  end
end

# In "qa" this command must succeed
if input('env') == 'qa'
  control "ipa-group-qa" do
    describe command('ipa group-show testgroup') do
      its('exit_status') { should eq 0 }
    end
  end
end
```

We can run the test by passing the value of `env` as input, example:

```
inspec exec testgroup_test.rb --input env=dev
```

Comment: sesadri_c thanks for your valuable input, btw is it possible to get customized  output in your code.  mean if the condition throw output as "testgroup presents"  or "testgroup not available"

Comment: I think what you are trying to achieve with inspec does not fit with its design. Please see if [custom inspec resources](https://docs.chef.io/inspec/dsl_resource/) works for you. Else, you should look at other tools (even Shell script at a rudimentary level).